# How to access model from selecteditem in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's assume that we have a simple model like this:

```cs
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A corresponding viewmodel:

```cs
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _person.Name; }  
    }

    private Person _person; 

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }  

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

And finally a viewmodel to display our persons:

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel SelectedPerson { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

On the view side we have something like this:

```xaml
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

How can I get access to the model which is wrapped in the SelectedPerson field in MVVM way?

Comment: Turn `private Person _person` into a public property. Then get `SelectedPerson.Person`. Alternatively derive PersonViewModel from Person. Then SelectedPerson is a Person. And you would save a Name property.

Comment: I was thinking about public property, but isn't exposing model to view violate MVVM principles ? 

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/MVVMPattern.png"

Usually viewmodels derive from viewmodelbase class, so deriving from person class definitely is not an option.

Comment: Exposing a property like this doesn't violate anything. Deriving is of course an option, because you're not forced to derive from any "viewmodelbase" class (if it's "usual" is matter of taste).

Comment: It allows the view bind to the model bypassing the view, which is smelly.

Comment: Well, that's nonsense. But why you're asking at all? You seem to know better anyway.

Comment: >>typo: bypassing the viewmodel. I'm just curious to know if there is a better way to do it ;).

Comment: You want to access Person without making it accessible, which makes not much sense. There is an answer that you should just accept.

Answer (score 0):

Add an access `public` for your `Person`

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _person;
    public Person Person
    {
        get
        {
            return _person;
        }
        set
        {
            _person = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, call :

```
SelectedPerson.Person
```